# Vectorizing a nested for loop which fills a dynamic programming table

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization, vectorization

I was wondering if there was a way to vectorize the nested for loop in this function which is filling up the entries of the 2D dynamic programming table DP. I believe that at the very least the inner loop could be vectorized as each row only depends on the previous row. I'm not sure how to do it though. Note this function is called on large 2D arrays (images) so the nested for loop really doesn't cut it.

```
function [cols] = compute_seam(energy)
    [r, c, ~] = size(energy);

    cols = zeros(r);

    DP = padarray(energy, [0, 1], Inf);    
    BP = zeros(r, c);

    for i = 2 : r        
        for j = 1 : c
            [x, l] = min([DP(i - 1, j), DP(i - 1, j + 1), DP(i - 1, j + 2)]);
            DP(i, j + 1) = DP(i, j + 1) + x;
            BP(i, j) = j + (l - 2);
        end
    end

    [~, j] = min(DP(r, :));
    j = j - 1;

    for i = r : -1 : 1
        cols(i) = j;
        j = BP(i, j);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Vectorization of the innermost nested loop

You were right in postulating that at least the inner loop is vectorizable. Here's the modified code for the nested loops part -

```
rows_DP = size(DP,1); %// rows in DP

%// Get first row linear indices for a group of neighboring three columns, 
%// which would be incremented as we move between rows with the row iterator
start_ind1 = bsxfun(@plus,[1:rows_DP:2*rows_DP+1]',[0:c-1]*rows_DP); %//'
for i = 2 : r
    ind1 = start_ind1 + i-2; %// setup linear indices for the row of this iteration
    [x,l] = min(DP(ind1),[],1); %// get x and l values in one go
    DP(i,2:c+1) = DP(i,2:c+1) + x; %// set DP values of a row in one go
    BP(i,1:c) = [1:c] + l-2; %// set BP values of a row in one go
end
```

---

### Benchmarking

Benchmarking Code -

```
N = 3000; %// Datasize
energy = rand(N);
[r, c, ~] = size(energy);

disp('------------------------------------- With Original Code')
DP = padarray(energy, [0, 1], Inf);
BP = zeros(r, c);
tic
for i = 2 : r
    for j = 1 : c
        [x, l] = min([DP(i - 1, j), DP(i - 1, j + 1), DP(i - 1, j + 2)]);
        DP(i, j + 1) = DP(i, j + 1) + x;
        BP(i, j) = j + (l - 2);
    end
end
toc,clear DP BP x l

disp('------------------------------------- With Vectorized Code')
DP = padarray(energy, [0, 1], Inf);
BP = zeros(r, c);
tic
rows_DP = size(DP,1); %// rows in DP
start_ind1 = bsxfun(@plus,[1:rows_DP:2*rows_DP+1]',[0:c-1]*rows_DP); %//'
for i = 2 : r
    ind1 = start_ind1 + i-2; %// setup linear indices for the row of this iteration
    [x,l] = min(DP(ind1),[],1); %// get x and l values in one go
    DP(i,2:c+1) = DP(i,2:c+1) + x; %// set DP values of a row in one go
    BP(i,1:c) = [1:c] + l-2; %// set BP values of a row in one go
end
toc
```

Results -

```
------------------------------------- With Original Code
Elapsed time is 44.200746 seconds.
------------------------------------- With Vectorized Code
Elapsed time is 1.694288 seconds.
```

Thus, you might enjoy a good `26x speedup` improvement in performance with that little vectorization tweak.

---

### More tweaks

Few more optimization tweaks could be tried into your code for performance -

- `cols = zeros(r)` could be replaced with `col(r,r) = 0`.
- `DP = padarray(energy, [0, 1], Inf)` could be replaced with 
  `DP(1:size(energy,1),1:size(energy,2)+2)=Inf; 
  DP(:,2:end-1) = energy;`
- `BP = zeros(r, c)` could be replaced with `BP(r, c) = 0`.

The pre-allocation tweaks used here are inspired by [this blog post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance).